# Dealing with multiple array value

Tags: python

I am creating a newArrayList. Each of signalxOP array minus with gradient and multiple with each of appliedFieldOP array. `(SignalxOP[] - Gradient) * appliedFieldOP[]`

How can i do that?? Below is the method i tried. It keep giving me error.

```
signalxOP = [5,4,3,2,1]
appliedFieldOP= [1,0.5,0,-0.5,-1]
Gradient = 1.5

newList = [[(x-Gradient)*y] for x,y in signalxOP,appliedFieldOP]
py.plot(appliedFieldOP,newList)
py.show()
```

## Error show

```
newList = [[(x-Gradient)*y] for x,y in signalxOP,appliedFieldOP]
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function, like this

```
newList = [[(x-Gradient)*y] for x,y in zip(signalxOP,appliedFieldOP)]
```

Comment: One probably should use [`izip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) in situations like that. However, this doesn't really matter for short lists.

Comment: @Suor: I'd go farther and say `zip` is _better_ when you know they're short. Going out of your way to use `izip` implies that you're expecting potentially-large data (and that you're willing to gratuitously break 3.x compatibility, possibly scare off a few novices, and make your code a little slower on small data to do so), which is misleading when you're sure that you have small lists.

Comment: @abarnert `izip` is still faster, even for short lists. Try `timeit [x + y for x, y in zip(l, l)]` in `ipython` and same with `izip`.

Comment: @Suor: I don't know what your `l` is, but when I try it with `l=[1,2]` (Apple 64-bit CPython 2.7.5) it's 776ns for `izip` and 639ns for `zip`. So, that's slower, not faster. But more importantly, you're focusing on the least important part of a parenthetical aside and ignoring the actual point.